# How to replicate object and field data that you see when defining a custom button

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am trying to create a dynamic link like this on salesforce\:

```
https://xyz.abc.com/atlas/launcher/eos/Opps?id=19438
&eos[0].Id={!Opportunity.Id}
&eos[0].System=Salesforce
&eos[0].Type=Opportunity
&eos[0].Name={!Opportunity.Name}
&eos[0].ScmPath=/Accounts/{!Opportunity.Account.Name}
```

here the path as a name is used for location example :

```
Folder name
{!Opportunity.Name}

Path
/Accounts/{!Opportunity.Account.Name}
```

As to use the path dynamically , i am unable to create a dynamic custom button. as mentioned above. Is there any possibility

Comment: What is the issue that you are running into?  If the special characters are causing issues you may be able to use the urlfor function to html encode the output.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to enclose the field values like `{!Opportunity.Name}` in either double quote mark marks like eg: `"{!Opportunity.Name}"` or single quotes (not certain which, but I suspect double) since they get evaluated at run time and aren't absolute values which is probably what's causing difficulties with saving them.

Comment: what does `eos[0].fldname` reference?  something in the controller? Javascript?

Comment: @crop1645 the value for the array eos[] formed dynamically , Regarding my question I am unable to set the same url for dynamic values in button

Comment: you will need to include the custom button code in your OP